# How do I manage My Computer?

Tags: windows, file-organization

My Computer is completely cluttered with folders and highly disorganized.
Today, I wanted to take a backup but I couldn't because I didn't know what to backup and what not to, and I did not want to backup unwanted stuff...
Is there any tool (preferably open-source/freeware) that I could use to organize the folders on my computer?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Windows?

Comment: Yes! OS is Windows!

Comment: No tool will tell you which directories are not required or unused by some installed product.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking how to solve a human problem (organization) with a technological solution. No software can decide for you what files are important to you personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, it's up to you. But tools like [Overdisk](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/overdisk.html) can help you by visualising a disk. The brilliant [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) will search for it, and a good explorer type tool like [Free commander](http://www.freecommander.com/) will help you to put files and folders where you want them.

Answer (score 1):

No automated tool is going to be able to figure out what you want to back up and what you don't want to without you telling it.

Comment: That's a good one! what do you suggest alternatively!

Comment: I'd suggest organizing your files in a way that it is easy to tell what you want.

Comment: No tool will tell you which product you will break if you move a directory.

Comment: I was assuming he wants to back up non-application related files, maybe it was a poor assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other guys have said there's nothing that's going to automate this and in most cases the onus is on you. I think the best approach to take will be to list down all the progams that you use and then locate all files on your computer. I'm sure you would know where you keep them and the way to go is to first backup everything that you know and where you saved them. In most cases that'd be fine but you may want to make backups of other things like email, etc, for which it's best if you take this as a step two and then post to the community for help if you get stuck.

The right idea is to mark the apps that you use most and then try to find a way to back them up. Hope this helps!

Comment: How should I mark apps?

Comment: It's not a feature, by that I meant, just list them. Thanks :)